# Particle hair does not follow rigged mesh

Tags: particles

I have got a rigged character (and I can't share therefore) to which I have to add particle hair to its head. I did this by creating two vertex groups (left/right) on the head and added two particle systems accordingly. Everything worked fine so far.

Then I moved the head via the rig - parts of the hair strands got tear off the scalp and remain like a "trace of motion blur" hanging in the air between the point, where the movement start and
where it ends.

This happens with Blender 2.91 / 2.92 and the newest 2.93.

The hair is not "disconnected".

How can I avoid this crazy effect???

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: This effect vanishes, when the particle system is located after/below the subsurface modifier.